# Como reproducir un video en una pagina especifica de mi proyecto?

Tags: java, android-studio, video

He diseñado una web app que funcion en android y ahora debo colocar videos en uan seccion de la misma, he investigadoel metodo VideoView, sin embargo al ejecutar la app aparece una pantalla en negro y no hace nada.

---

Asi es mi activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Y eso es lo que segun he investigado debo agregar

```
<VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

Asi es mi MainActivity.java

```
package com.worktoolslleida.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String PDF_PATH = "com.worktoolslleida.app.PDF_PATH";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView view = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
                openPDF(url);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }

            return false;

        }


    });



    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl("file:android_asset/index.html");
}

private void openPDF(String url) {
    String path = url.substring(22);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PDFActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PDF_PATH, path);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

---

ESTO ES LO QUE DEBO AGREGAR AL MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
    VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.worktoolslleida.app;" +  R.raw.springyclaber);

MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
```

Sin embargo no se si simplemente insertar los codigos justo debajo es lo que afecta el comportamiento de la app o que sucede.

Busco algo de asesoria pues soy muy novato en esto y lo que he logrado lo he logrado con ayuda de amigos y por investigacion propia.

Intuyo que quizas deba crear nuevas Activities para que funcionen con la reproduccion del video asi como lo tengo gracias a un buen amigo para que ejecute archivos PDF.

Mientras hago esas pruebas cuelgo esto por aqui esperando alguna ayuda.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente cuando he tratado de trabajar con audio y video he utilizado la librería [Exoplayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer) . Maneja muchas cosas internamente y es muy fácil de utilizar, hay mucha documentación al respecto.

Tengo un ejemplo de videos que te puede servir.

https://github.com/RaulitoGC/Udacity-Baking-App